# selenium c# auto follow in instagram

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bots

I build for myself an auto follow to my instagram account. Until now it worked fine.
Now its not working anymore, here is the code:

```
driver.FindElement((By.XPath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span"))).Click();
```

I am trying to open followers tab in instagram profile, it worked perfect until now. Someone can help me with this?

html code:

```
<a class="-nal3 " href="/nailsworld24/followers/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY " title="341,338">341k</span> followers</a>
```

Comment: Have you checked if html structure changed? Perhaps the xpath is no longer valid.

Comment: Now its not working anymore, what is the error stack trace ? Also please update the question with relevant HTML Code.

Comment: Hey I check if its changed, And I think that the code not changed, here is html code:
`<a class="-nal3 " href="/nailsworld24/followers/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY " title="341,338">341k</span> followers</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not standard in programing,
you can use some library like InstagramApiSharp nuget package.